# Evaluating similarity of sequences based on whether the sequences could have been drawn from the same probability distribution

Tags: python, sequence, similarity

I have multiple sequences with elements drawn from a specific set (e.g. *A, B, C, ...*). The length of the different sequences is not necessarily equal. Typical lengths are on the order of 100 to 400 elements.

I want to calculate the probability of finding each element at a relative location in the chain. In other words, I want to find the probability of encountering an element at location *x* in the sequence, where *x* is normalized to the length of the sequence. So if the sequences are constructed using *N* elements, the set of sequences would then be described by *N* probability functions. Provided that all sequences are constructed using the same set of probability functions, this should be relatively straightforward to solve.

However, I cannot assume that all sequences have been drawn from the same probability functions. In fact, it is likely that the set of sequences contain one or more sub-populations. Hence I first need to sort the list of sequences into appropriate sub-populations before I can calculate the probability functions.

How can I find out:

1. How many sub-populations exist in my set of sequences;
2. and which sequence belongs to which sub-population?

In case it matters, I am using Python.

Comment: I feel that's more of a statistics question than a programming question. Some pointers to start from: you won't have to know what sub-population a sequence comes from, but have to be able to express a membership believe in form of a probability distribution. From this POV sub-population membership is a [latent variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_variable). If you want to optimize this kind of model, you will likely end up with some form of [Expectation Maximization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) scheme.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It may indeed be more of a statistics question, but your comment at least gives a helpful starting point.